# How can I make it so my symbology updates when new data is entered into a field in Arcgis Field Maps?

Tags: field, arcgis, arcpy

I am working on a project where we have a line feature layer with empty fields that will be filled via data collectors using Arcgis Field Maps. The symbology just shows a black line for all the records, but I would like to make it so when they enter in information to any field it updates the symbology to some other color, thus showing which parts of the feature class have been updated. Anyone have any ideas?

I've looked around ESRI's documentation and I haven't found anything that may help me with this. I am new to using things like Arcpy so I would really appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You would do conditional symbology with arcade language. Here is some documentation to get you started.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/production/aviation/write-arcade-expressions-for-symbology-and-labeling.htm
Hope this helps will check back for specific issues in implementing.